# dynamically executing classic ASP pages

Tags: asp-classic

I'd like to store the contents of classic ASP pages in a table in a database, and have the ability to dynamically retrieve said contents and execute on the fly.  Is this possible?

Comment: Ug.  I'm sure it's possible, but I'd have to ask why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text from the database, save it to a temporal .asp file in the website, and then execute a Server.Execute(tempfile). Don't forget to delete the tempfile...

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the "[Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2%28VS.85%29.aspx)" statement.

```
Dim aspCode
aspCode = getCodeFromDB() ' I assume you can handle this part
Execute aspCode
```

This will even work if your db-driven ASP has "Option Explicit" at the very top.

That said, the general idea of having ASP code live inside a database sounds a bit iffy to me, but to each their own, and I wish you luck!

Comment: Actually, Execute doesn't work.    Server.Execute against a path, on the other hand, does work.

Comment: Execute will execute actual VB Script.  However an ASP file that has inline <% and %> as well as HTML markup will not work.   I have about a BILLION legacy asp reports that i need to archive and control access to.  Much easier to corrale them in a DB than to modify each file.

Comment: I don't understand how this is considered strange, since Facebook and many other websites literally did this same thing, except they cheaped out and went Linux instead of Microsoft Servers.  (php vs asp)

Comment: @easleyfixed, props for necromancing a 14 year old question. The present version of myself agrees with the past version of myself: this is strange. My reasoning then, as it is now, is that the best place to keep code is in source control. Without additional details, the idea of keeping code in a database implies a lack of source control. NoCarrier's clarification that there are a billion legacy files, if taken at face value, would be sufficient to consider such a solution in spite of strangeness.

Comment: of course .. it is easier to edit an ASP file than access the data in the database.  But I was just saying that its not strange to store the pages into a database when you start to get so many pages that locating all the files would require a formula to arrange them.   But yeah in no means was this is a slight against the answer, it is correct,  I suppose i prefer the word dynamic to strange.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody was able to make the Execute (actually ExecuteGlobal) concept work.  I tried using this some years ago as a test and it did indeed work.  I believe the real problem would come when you want to debug inside your 1000 line ExecuteGlobal statement.

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7651&lngWId=4

Basically, the asp text is parsed and items within <%=%> and <% %> are handled appropriately.

For instance

```
    <%=var1 & "-" & var2%> 
would convert to
    response.write var1 & "-" & var2
```

and

```
  <%
  Hello, this is html
  %>
would convert to 
  response.write "Hello, this is html"
```