# Splicing ASP code into ASP page

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP page that I would like to dynamically splice a chunk of ASP code from a database field into at runtime. I do not want to write the database field, I want to run the code. It looks something like this (I am aware this will fail on line 3):

```
<% ' THIS IS THE HOST PAGE WITH A RECORDSET ALREADY CREATED TO PULL IN THE ASP
response.write "Welcome to the host page..."       
rs("ASPcode")
%>
```

At the moment I am using a an include with the code in it and am calling a function in the host ASP using `Eval(rs("functionNameHere"))` but it is a bit cumbersome.

What is the most elegant way of splicing the code from the database into the host page? Is there some marvelous function that I can wrap `rs("ASPcode")` in?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Yeah it's called `Execute`

Comment: Actually did you search first? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1408426/692942

Comment: Thanks Lanky, that is what I was after. I had searched for an answer before posting my question but could only find answers where people said dynamic pages are impossible and asking why on earth someone would want to pull code from a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered by Lankymart in his comments. I used `Execute()` and it worked fine.